# Compare two dates in SQL Server with between statement and remove time from datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to compare two dates in a SQL Server database with `between` statement and remove time from it's value?

This is my code:

```
select 
    sum(TbDeals.dealPrice) as sumofvalues 
from 
    DNN_TbDeals
where 
    Deals.dealStartDate between Convert(Date, Convert(datetime, '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233')) 
                            and Convert(Date, Convert(datetime, '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233'))
```

Comment: So what's the error you are getting?

Comment: it's return null. whereas when i use datetime as string, return sum correctly.

Comment: You don't have to convert '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233' string to datetime. Have you tired that?

Comment: It must be related to the type of the column `dealStartDate`. Does the column `dealStartDate` have a `date` type?

Comment: no, its datetime format

Comment: @VladimirBaranov See the dates the OP posted. They are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Deals.dealStartDate` is a `DateTime` column, you don't have to convert twice - If you want to do a `between` 2 dates, convert it once with a fixed format, this way you don't have to remove the time string.

Also - in your question, you posted a `between` with the **exact same dates**. This is probably the reason you are getting no results.

Please try the following:

```
select sum(TbDeals.dealPrice) as sumofvalues 
from DNN_TbDeals
where 
    Deals.dealStartDate
    between 
        Convert(datetime, '2016-01-01 22:21:16.233', 101)
    and 
        Convert(datetime, '2017-08-28 22:21:16.233', 101)
```

Comment: thanks friend. in web page, we have a datepicker that send selected date to database(it send date only, without time), now we want to calculate sum of deals in given date range.

Comment: @masoudamirian Are you testing my solution in a web page? Can you run the query straight in the database? Also - Again - What dates DO you have int the database, which should return in the query? Give me some date examples.

Comment: 2017-07-10 22:21:16.233
2017-07-11 02:25:58.213
2017-07-12 15:33:27.290

Comment: And when you run my query in the database, no results ?

Comment: i run queries in sql server

Comment: @masoudamirian You keep writing on every answer that the solution does not work - clearly you have a problem somewhere else, and not in the dates. Have you checked other directions?

Comment: @masoudamirian is that really your column datatype format is datetime or something else .if it is really datetime then  Koby Douek answer should work for you with no issues. just cross with your tables and data instead of repeatedly saying it is not working .

Comment: @KobyDouek it won't kill me if i reward you with upvote .But i would have really impressed if you use `CONVERT(datetime, Yourdate_as_string, 103)'  rather than `CONVERT(datetime, Yourdate_as_string, 101)` .Beacuse most of the developes follow dateformat like `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of `mm/dd/yyyy`.Anyway catch my rewards .Appreciate you with upvote . -:)

Comment: @Mahesh.K Thanks man. But still, what do you mean? I **did** use 103...

Comment: @KobyDouek  My pleasure ..yeah..thats what i mean exactly .sorry for my english .

Comment: @Mahesh.K I'm lost here... I did use 103, reading your comment you suggest using 103... Did you mean I should have used 101?

Comment: @Mahesh.K Edited accordingly. Living in Israel I'm used to `dd/mm/yyyy` format but I guess you're right.

Comment: @KobyDouek i'm sorry man.i thought you have used 101 `mm/dd/yyy`.103 `dd/mm/yyyy` is correct  Anyway great -;)

Comment: @Mahesh.K Let's hope India's and Israel's uprising relationship are as productive as ours. Peace brother.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEDIFF date built in function

```
SELECT SUM(TbDeals.dealPrice) as sumofvalues 
FROM DNN_TbDeals
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,Deals.dealStartDate,'2017-07-10 22:21:16.233') <= 0 AND
      DATEDIFF(DAY,Deals.dealStartDate,'2017-07-10 22:21:16.233') >= 0
```

Comment: thanks. but it returns 52010 for all period of dates.

Comment: @masoudamirian,What is your date range

Comment: between days.even for 1 day user should able to calculate sum of deals.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood well your question, to compare two datetimes format where the differences are in the hours, you can do:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,@DATETIME1,@DATETIME2) AS DIFFERENCES
```

To take the hours from a datetime variable you can do:

```
DECLARE @dateTime2 AS DATETIME = '2013-04-04 00:00:00.000'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@dateTime2, 101)
```

In you case, if you want to compare two dates and then take the hours your query can be like:

```
DECLARE @dateTime1 AS DATETIME= '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233'
DECLARE @dateTime2 AS DATETIME= '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233'

SELECT
    SUM(TbDeals.dealPrice) ASsumofvalues 
FROM
    DNN_TbDeals
WHERE
    Deals.dealStartDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,@dateTime1,101)
                            AND CONVERT(DATE,@dateTime2,101)
```

Comment: @masoudamirian You keep writing on every answer that the solution does not work - clearly you have a problem somewhere else, and not in the dates. Have you checked other directions?

Comment: exactly. you can test these answers on sql server.

Comment: You can test it if you have the right data model with the right data type. My query is working on sql server. Is you dealStartDate a date or a datetime?

Answer (score 0):

From your code

```
where 
    Deals.dealStartDate between Convert(Date, Convert(datetime, '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233')) 
                            and Convert(Date, Convert(datetime, '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233'))
```

IF we remove hours from your given dates then both between dates will be same like

```
where 
    Deals.dealStartDate between '2017-07-10' and '2017-07-10'
```

This may not give you and results obviously.But if your dates are really different then the below query may help you.

```
SELECT SUM(TbDeals.dealPrice) as sumofvalues 
FROM DNN_TbDeals
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, Yourdate_as_string, 103) <=  CONVERT(datetime, Yourdate_as_string, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum function column,CONVERT(nvarchar,DateColumnName,101) DateColumnName  
from tableName where DateColumnName between '08/28/2017' and '08/30/2017'
```

Comment: @ masoud amirian  try the above query

Comment: Can you add an explanation of your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use CONVERT() and might have a need to use ISNULL()

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(TbDeals.dealPrice,0)) AS sumofvalues 
  FROM DNN_TbDeals
 WHERE Deals.dealStartDate BETWEEN '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233'
                               AND '2017-07-10 22:21:16.233';
```